# How to get state from one react component to another?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, components

I'm new in ReactJS, that's why i'm here.
I created a component 'Login' and have variable 'isAuthenticated' in this.state.

[image]

After user login I change value of this variable to true and my app redirect user to home page.
[image]

In main page I must to check 'isAuthenticated' value and rerender component depends on it.

[image]

But it's not working. I got error: "Unable to get property 'setState' of undefined or null reference".

Please help me how to fix it all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using something like [Redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction) for your state management I suggest you use the [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage) of the browser to store that value for isAuthenitcated. Something like

```
localStorage.setItem('isAuthenticated', true); - on login
```

then in the other component you can use:

```
localStorage.getItem('isAuthenticated'); - to figure out what you want to show
```

remember to set isAuthenticated to false on logout as well!

```
localStorage.setItem('isAuthenticated', false); - on logout
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you will be having a login function like below

```
function login(){
   doLogin().then(function(data){
     this.setState({isAuthentcated: true});
  });
}
```

Bind the login function to the component using ES6 Arrow function like this

```
login = () => {
       doLogin().then((data) => {
         this.setState({isAuthentcated: true});
      });
    }
```